# Query Sharepoint for custom code and modified date

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, caml

Using CAML or some other query system, how can I find items that use custom code and organize by modified date?

---

And the background. My group is looking to upgrade a 2007 SharePoint installation to SPO. The problem we're having is a lack of clarity as to what on the site is junk and what is a custom code set. The first idea was just to run through manually and make note of every node. As there are 5,200 nodes, this is pure insanity. I've done some research to find that CAML is how to query a particular site in SharePoint, however I cannot seem to figure out how to query everything at the same time.

I tried to make a view in the root, but again, it only queries the particular level you're on. I'm having the feeling that I might need to write a tool for this and spider the site, but am unsure where to begin. After trying a couple of tools (Stramit Caml running in visual studio and SPUD) I seem to be running in place as I don't understand how the connection works.

Any advice or stories like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scan your environment and detect where custom solutions are used, your best bet is to use the `stsadm` command called [`preupgradecheck`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789638(v=office.12).aspx). This is executed from the commandline on one of your web front end servers, invoking `stsadm.exe`.

From [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793609(v=office.12).aspx):

> The Stsadm command provides a rule-based scanning operation to determine whether servers in an existing SharePoint environment meet the core requirements for upgrading from Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 and related products to future releases of SharePoint Products and Technologies.
>
> The pre-upgrade scanning and reporting operation is implemented as **Stsadm –o preupgradecheck**, and can be run with or without parameters.

Upon execution, the command checks your environment against various rules. The result of each rule check is written to both an XML log file and a text log file, located in the the `%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\LOGS` directory, and when the command finishes it will display an HTML file in the default web browser summarizing the results.

Comment: I'll have my services team run it and get back to me.

Comment: I have the report back. It does not look like we really have any custom solutions. Is there something I should be looking for in this report that might tip me off?

Comment: If the preupgradecheck didn't find any custom solutions, you're probably safe from the perils of custom code. Do you have reason to believe there's custom code despite the report?

Comment: I don't. I just want to make complete sure of myself before proceeding.